# What are some ways to say you have an ability to figure it out?

Tags: phrases, idiom-requests

I have a summary section on my resume and am trying to figure out how to say I'm able to say "Software Engineer with a strong ability to pick up and learn new technologies and concepts." in stronger language.

I'm trying to find something more professional than "thrown to the wolves", "thrown in the fire", or "have a knack for". I have really good problem solving skills and am able to find a solution for most things (this is just one of the places I'm researching).

For context this is my whole summary:

> Software Engineer with a strong ability to pick up and learn new technologies and concepts. I also love Typescript, React, and Ruby.

It really needs to remain around the same length.

Comment: Resume language has to address two groups of readers: screeners and hiring managers. It’s hard to strike the right tone with both. Generally speaking, though, terms like “I love” applied to tools (like a programming language) tend to strike people as slightly off, somewhat like a bus driver professing a love for steering wheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your competition I must admit that it is not a bad phrase.

"with a strong ability to pick up and learn new technologies and concepts."

I might trim it down from redundancies to;

"with a strong ability to learn new technologies."

I cannot think of anything shorter that does not get too cute, such as "vertical learning curve" or "thrown to the wolves" as you mention.